# How can i update records of one CustomObject with the other Custom Object

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to salesforce developement....thanx

```
trigger updateFieldsOnObject2 on Object1__c (after insert) 
{
    for(Object1__c o1 : trigger.new)
    {
       List<String> listOfFields = [select name,country__c from Object1__c where Object1__c.Id = : o1.Id];

       for(Object2__c o2 : listOfFields)
       {
           o2.name = o1.name;
           o2.country__c = o1.country__C;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't right. You query Object1__c then try to loop through it as an Object2__c. You clearly need more insight into your attempt.

Comment: You can refer to this link..This will give you brief idea about apex fundamentals...http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_triggers.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_triggers.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: Code is logically incorrect. Also provide more possible details about the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

**General Observations**

In general you are heading down the correct path with Apex Triggers and the events you've taken. I would advise your next area of research is around the [platform limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm). So in further answer to your question the main observation being made here is the lack of something called '[bulkification](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm)'. It is a Saleforce concept to manage the number of times in one request your code perform operations that are governed (limited) by the platform.

**Bulkifcaiton Requirement**

In this case the number of database queries (SOQL queries) you can make in one request are limited as per the limits described [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm). Meaning that if your trigger received more than 100 items records for Object1__c (for example via data loaders or other bulk data insert tools) your code would hit a governor and the end user operation would fall and the database rollback. As you are performing a database query within a loop this is going to be the case for your trigger, so this needs changing.

Salesforce [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bulk_idioms.htm) does have a good topic on this. Generally bulkificaiton involves a pre-scan of the records your processing to accumulate a list of related records you want to query via one database query. Returning the results into an [in memory Map](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_map_sobject.htm) you can then update in your loop, before finally updating the modified records.

When performing database updates, you need to utilise [DML](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_dml_examples.htm) (Database Manipulate Language) statements, again these are also governed so its important to utilise these outside of loops. Hopefully the following will give you a better idea of 'bulkifcaiton' in use in respect to your use case.

```
trigger updateFieldsOnObject2 on Object1__c (after insert) {

    // Prescan references to Object2__c and make a list of Id's
    Set<Id> object2Ids = new Set<Id>();
    for(Object1__c o1 : trigger.new)
        if(o1.Object2__c!=null)
            object2Ids.add(o1.Object2__c);

    // Bulk query for your Object2__c records
    Map<Id, Object2__c> listOfObjects2 = 
        new Map<Id, Object2__c>([select name,country__c from Object2__c where id in :object2Ids]);

    for(Object1__c o1 : trigger.new)
    {
       // Skip Object1 records without any reference to a Object2 record
       if(o1.Object2__c==null)
          continue;

       // Update the in memory map of object 2 records
       Object2__c o2 = listOfObjects2.get(o1.Object2__c);
       o2.name = o1.name;
       o2.country__c = o1.country__C;
    }

    // Update the Object 2 records on the database
    update listOfObjects2.values();
}
```

**Some Additional Notes**

- A [Set](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) is used to capture the Id's for all the Object2 records referenced in advance. A Set is a form of List, that reflects the fact that the items in it are unique. A List could equally have been used, though if you received more than one Object1 record referencing the same Object2 record you would have duplicates in a List. Using a Set avoids this.
- A [Map](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm) is used to be able to lookup in memory the correct Object2 record by Id. Think of it as a kind of in memory index over related Object2 records.
- You can reference the [Trigger.new](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) collection at any point in the trigger, its contents does not change. There is no specific rules that state when and how often you can reference this collection. As per above, it is common practice to reference it at least twice if you have to bulkify your queries to related records before processing.

Comment: But can u be more specific on what each line of code does and why should we use these?... why is the **set** is used, why not **list** and what is the purpose of **MAP**?... Why are you coding trigger.new at the middle of the trigger as id is supposed to be at the top to get all the newly inserted data...  **learning once the code flow will help me to write my logic correct from next time**

Comment: Sure, I've added an additional notes section to my answer. Hope this helps give a bit more insight. Let me know if not. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First and foremore you need to read some [salesforce fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/).

Now, If you are trying to update an Object2 fields when a related Object1 is inserted you should try something like this:

```
trigger updateFieldsOnObject2 on Object1__c (after insert) 
{
    for(Object1__c o1 : trigger.new)
    {
       List<String> listOfObjects2 = [select name,country__c from Object2__c where id = :o1.Object2__c];

       for(Object2__c o2 : listOfObjects2)
       {
           o2.name = o1.name;
           o2.country__c = o1.country__C;
       }
    }
    update listOfObjects2;
}
```

When you understand this trying to improve this code to make it bulk-safe.

Comment: This is actually a very dangerous way of doing it. What if you do a bulk update of 101 Object1's? it will fail because you can only do 100 SOQL's.

Comment: That is the reason why I finish my post saying that this should be changed to bulk-safe way.  But, the user is quite new to understand two concepts together.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that one !